# How simple to rotate text in stringgrid in delphi?

Tags: delphi, rotation, tstringgrid

Is simple way to rotate text in stringgrid (90 and 45 degrees)? Or is there FREE component like TStringGrid with text rotation in cell?

Comment: See [SwissDelphiCenter](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1596) for an example (by Reinhard Schatzl) how to do this with 90 degrees rotation.

Comment: [This Lazarus answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9155357/757830) shows the Delphi solution at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Do not rotate image, draw the text rotated

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ZColorStringGrid](http://avemey.com/zcolorstringgrid/zcolorstringgrid.php?lang=en) component (free). Component have additional properties for each cells (text rotation, indent, color, alignment). Support multiline text (and can rotate multiline text) and merge cells.

Code sample:

```
  ZColorStringGrid1.CellStyle[0, 1].Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
  ZColorStringGrid1.CellStyle[0, 1].Font.Size := 12;
  ZColorStringGrid1.CellStyle[0, 1].Rotate := 90;
  ZColorStringGrid1.Cells[0, 1] := 'Rotate' + sLineBreak + 'text' + sLineBreak + '90 degrees';
```